# How to get mime type of mp3 returning application/octet-stream mime type?

Tags: php, laravel

I use

```
$file->isReadable()
```

to check if is readable ro not because MP3 and WMA doesn't work with

```
$file->getMimeType();
```

and when I use it gives me an error so I use

```
$file->getClientMimetype()
```

which returns `application/octet-stream` instead of `audio/mpeg`

[image]

is there a workaround it or a library to guess it by extension name?

I always need the `audio/` part for any type I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the finfo function to determine the MIME type of the file. The FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE flag is passed to finfo to specify that you want to get the MIME type. Then, the file() method is called on the finfo object, passing the file path as an argument, to retrieve the MIME type.

```
$file = '/path/to/your/file.mp3';

if (is_readable($file)) {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimeType = $finfo->file($file);
    
    // Extract the audio/ part of the MIME type
    $audioMimeType = substr($mimeType, 0, strpos($mimeType, '/')) . '/';

    echo $audioMimeType; // Output: audio/mpeg
} else {
    echo "File is not readable.";
}
```